# clear the memory consumed by Clob oracle

Tags: oracle, memory, clob, xmltype

I am using the below oracle select query in my java application

```
select a.xmlrecord.getClobVal() xmlrecord from tablename where ID like 'ABC%' order by ID
```

After executing the select query i am retrieving the output using the below code & closing the result set and connection at finally block

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(orset.getCharacterStream("xmlrecord"));
```

Suddenly i am facing the below error as shown below

```
   java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded 
   ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 107112 bytes
```

I have checked with my DBA and he insisted that the error is due to 
JDBC code is calling getclobVal() on xmltype and there is no check to see if it a temp lob and no code to free it explicitly.

Is there anything we need to close for Clob objects at the end of the method. Please note that i am just using the clobval() only in my query and no where else and i am not creating any Clob/lob object in my code.

Please provide your inputs on the above error.

Comment: You would use `DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(...);` However, as you just make a select and not a `SELECT .. INTO ...` this will not help because there is no variable declared.

Comment: yes, since we dont use clob object we cannot free the memory. Is there any other option to overcome the error mentioned above, Thanks

Comment: @APC: He is asking to look the code in order to release the memory.

Comment: So how big are the XML objects you're working with?

Comment: Its more than 5 million record count.

Comment: No, how big are the **XMLType** instances? That is, what is the total size in MB of the result set from the query you posted? Of course, if you're really retrieving five million records in a single query your DBA probably has a valid point regarding the need to rethink your code.

Comment: I am extracting only 100 thousand records using the selection criteria and the size of the xmlrecord per row is 3 MB..

Answer (score 1):

getClobVal() is a SQL function and it will instantiate a LOB object on the server and 
return the appropriate LOB locator to the Java client.

Even if it was originally created with a statement duration, the action of returning the locator to a client morphs the LOB into a session duration object.

You need to change your Java code to do something like ...

```
Clob xmlrecord = orset.getClob("xmlrecord"));
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(xmlrecord.getCharacterStream());
```

then you can then perform ...

```
  xmlrecord.free();
```

Depending on which version you are using, Oracle JDBC may free the object for you without intervention but you should always code this in anyway.  If the object has already been freed, then it's a no-op, else it will get closed and, if a temporary LOB, freeTemporary() will get called to release the resource on the server.

Bug fix 23205826 in 12.2.0.1 and in particular, bug fix 26335028 in 18.1 may help.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're extracting 100,000 rows and each row is 3 MB? So that's a 300 GB result set? Yikes. Since this is not PL/SQL, there's nothing for you to free. My guess is Oracle is just constructing a result set that's too big and you're exceeding your PGA.

Does this work if you retrieve just one row? You may have to get your results in batches.

Comment: Yes, while running my application the PGA is exceeding 32 GB...Also i am using stmt.setFetchSize(1000) before executing my select statement. Please advise.